# What is meaning/geometric interpretation of the Expectation parameters of a multivariate gaussian (exponential family)?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, exponential-family

According to page 17 of [Statistical exponential families](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.4863.pdf) the expectation parameters for a multivariate gaussian are given by
$$
\boldsymbol{H}=\left(\mu,-(\Sigma+\mu\mu^T)\right)=(\eta,H)
$$
I am having difficulty understanding the $H$ term. Since $H$ is our new "covariance", how does adding $\mu\mu^T$ affect it or how is this transformation useful?

I tried setting a simple Toy model to help me understand but still struggling. Lets say we have
$$ 
\mathbf {X} \ \sim \ {\mathcal {N}}({\boldsymbol {\mu }},{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }})
$$
where $\mu_a = \begin{pmatrix} 0  \\  0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ then $H_a=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, with eigenvalues $(1,1)$ and eigenvectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$

then if $\mu_b = \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\  1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ then $H_b=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ with eigenvalues $(3,1)$ and eigenvectors $(1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2})$ and $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$

So it seems like outer product of the mean stretches and rotates covariance the higher away from the mean is from $(0,0)$, but that doesn't make any sense. Am I thinking misinterpreting or calculating $H$ wrong?

Comment: $\Sigma+\mu\mu^\prime$ is the matrix of second moments: this is an immediate consequence of the definition of $\Sigma$ as the matrix of central second moments.  $\mu,$ of course, is the vector of first moments.

Comment: @whuber ok so it seem like shouldn't be interpreting this as a new covariance matrix? Do you have any good references for understanding 2nd moments of multivariate/bivariate gaussians

Comment: A full and fairly elementary discussion of multivariate moments (and cumulants) appears in Kendall, Stuart, & Ord Volume I.  It has probably been there since the first edition; I learned it from the third edition.  There's nothing special about moments of Gaussians, and all that's going on here is a tiny bit of algebra, so don't try to read too much into it.